# Different web technologies on different directory in the same website, is it possible? (picture attached)

Tags: wordpress, dns, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I'm using Google Cloud Platform and I would like to host 2 websites on the same domain as below:

- Web App using its own technology - www.example.com
- A Blog using Wordpress technology - www.example.com/blog

Is it possible to achieve this?
[Schema Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCoOr.png)

Thanks!

Comment: First of all the given two links are not two separate websites. You can create as many directories as you want in your website like ` www.example.com/help` ,  `www.example.com/aboutme` But keep in mind this are not the separate websites.

Comment: You Should Name your question to: **Different web technologies on different directory in the same website**

Comment: @ankitsuthar Thanks, I just change my title...I'm wondering how can I achieve this

Comment: it's simple. in Blog Directory You can setup your WordPress or any other framework and in the main directory, you can use any other framework.